# Rails deserialize format output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, serialization, hash

I face a problem, I don't know how to arrange the serialize format in rails.

I have models call `MissionSet`, `QuestionSet`, `Group`

The MissionSet will return like [this](https://gist.github.com/fifiteen82726/37936af2ed8e86df692c3e681cd34904)

I want it to become like [this](https://gist.github.com/fifiteen82726/b6e216c29ba8a2f2fa98a0ccc8ff7770), it's really a challenge to me, because I am not familiar with handling this format.

Comment: What is your  question? Have you tried something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that will get you started:

```
x = {}

inp.each do |h|
  h['assignments'].each do |k, _|
    x[k] ||= []
    x[k] << h['question_set_id']
  end
end

out = x.map do |key, value|
  {
      group_id: key,
      question_sets: value.map { |v| { id: v} }
  }
end

puts out.inspect
```

This code will first group your questions by the ids in `assignments` and then format it as you wanted.